# How do I count rows with two properties in one index scan in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I have a table `Units` where I have rows `ItemId`, `ItemCreationDate`, `ItemUnitsCount`. `ItemId` is a primary key and I have a clustered index over it.

I need to output the following: for each day I need to count **separately**

1. items that were created in that day and have *zero* `ItemUnitsCount`
2. items that were created in that day and have *nonzero* `ItemUnitsCount`

and output the count and the date and on any day there can be any number of item of both kinds, maybe none. Each kind of items should be reported **separately**, so for any day I can have no rows, one row or two rows.

So I crafted the following query:

```
(SELECT ItemCreationDate, COUNT(ItemId) AS ComputedCount, 1 AS CountType
   FROM Items WHERE ItemUnitsCount<>0 GROUP BY ItemCreationDate )
UNION ALL
(SELECT ItemCreationDate, COUNT(ItemId) AS ComputedCount, 2 AS CountType
   FROM Items WHERE ItemUnitsCount=0 GROUP BY ItemCreationDate )
```

and this works okay, but when I looks at the actual execution plan I see two clustered index scans one of which has predicate `ItemUnitsCount=0` and another has predicate `ItemUnitsCount<>0`.

`ItemUnitsCount` can be changed several times over lifetime of the table row, so I'd rather not build an index for it.

Is there a way to build a query with the same effect that results in one index scan instead of two?

Comment: Is it ok to output the result in 1 row? If so, it's easy

Comment: @Phil: Nope, that should be separate rows.

Comment: You have this question tagged for both 2008 R2 and Azure.  Is that correct? (Not that it matters for the question, just for categorization.)

Comment: @Nick Chammas: I heard that SQL Azure is a modified version of SQL Server 2k8 R2. Not sure though.

Comment: Yes, it's the ["cloud" version of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336241.aspx), hosted and managed by Microsoft with major administration differences and some important feature differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by your condition

```
SELECT
    ItemCreationDate,
    COUNT(ItemId) AS ComputedCount,
    CASE WHEN ItemUnitsCount = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS CountType
FROM
    Items
GROUP BY
    ItemCreationDate,
    CASE WHEN ItemUnitsCount = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END;
```

Comment: This is the simplest, most direct solution to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    ItemCreationDate
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ItemUnitsCount <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountType1
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ItemUnitsCount = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountType2
FROM
    dbo.Items
GROUP BY
    ItemCreationDate
```

Comment: He wants them on separate rows I think...

Comment: @JNK A `PIVOT` should do the trick.